# не- со словами в роли сказуемого

Tags: грамматика

В безличных предложениях слова, являющиеся главными членами предложения, должны писаться раздельно с приставкой не-? Или это зависит от общего правила?

Comment: Пример дайте, пожалуйста. Не совсем понятно, о чем вы.. .

Comment: @behemothus имеются в виду предикативы. (Не)важно, как...; (не)понятно, что... и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Главные члены безличного предложения:** 1) безличные глаголы (и личные глаголы в значении безличных);  2) слова категории состояния (предикативы); 3) краткие страдательные причастия.

**В каждом случае действуют свои правила.** Глаголы и краткие причастия пишутся с ***не*** раздельно (кроме исключений): *не хочется, не надоело, нездоровится; не положено, не суждено.*

**Разные формы написания имеют предикативы**, к ним относятся предикативные наречия на ***-о***, а также слова *пора, жаль, недосуг* и др.

Выбор формы написания для предикативных наречий на ***-о*** и этих слов делается **по правилу Розенталя** ([Частица ***не*** с наречиями](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81)):

> **5.** Слова категории состояния на ***-о*** (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей ***не*** слитно при утверждении: *нетрудно видеть* и раздельно при отрицании: ***не** трудно видеть* (смысл обычно устанавливается самим пишущим).
> <...>
> **7.** Частица ***не*** пишется раздельно:
> <...>
> **2)** со словами категории состояния (предикативными наречиями), не соотносительными с прилагательными: ***не** надо, **не** время, **не** жаль* (но: *недосуг, неохота* и др.).